# MySQL procedure to update a price based on a date change

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to write a procedure that update the the content in one column, based a change in date is more than 20 days. In context, the procedure decreases the price of a good if the time passed since acquired is more than 20 days.

I am using the DATEDIFF function as well as GETDATE() statement but I am really strugling. At this point I am stucked.

Can anybody tell what is wrong with my sql code?

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE UPDATE_PRICE 

DECLARE @TIMEPASSED AS TIME
SET @TIMEPASSED = GETDATE()

BEGIN 
UPDATE sales SET  sales.SalesPrice = sales.SalesPrice - 30 
WHERE DATEDIFF(@GETDATE(), Sales.AcquisitionDate;

END;;
```

Any help on this one would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable declarations should be in the `BEGIN`/`END` block, but they are not really needed in this case.  `GETDATE()` is not a MySQL function.  So:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE UPDATE_PRICE 
BEGIN 
    UPDATE sales s
        SET s.SalesPrice = s.SalesPrice - 30 
        WHERE s.AcquisitionDate < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 20 day;
END;

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE UPDATE_PRICE 

DECLARE @TIMEPASSED AS TIME
SET @TIMEPASSED = GETDATE()

BEGIN 
UPDATE sales SET  sales.SalesPrice = sales.SalesPrice - 30 
WHERE DATEDIFF(@GETDATE(), Sales.AcquisitionDate) > 20;

END;
```